# SpringBootRequestHandler for a GET call

Tags: java, spring-boot, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, spring-cloud

I am currently using Spring Cloud Function, and I want to deploy my GET function on AWS Lambda, using the adapter for AWS.

Till now all the Spring Cloud Function implemented was a single POST function with the following structure.

This was done using the
SpringBootRequestHandler.

The DemoRequest class was a POJO class defined to accept the request body and DemoResponse is for the response.

I understand that this part of the code is Depricated.

Interface to define the Endpoint:

```
@SuppressWarnings("hiding")
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Demoapi<DemoRequest, DemoResponse>{
@PostMapping(value = "/v1/demo")
public ResponseEntity<DemoResponse> demo(@RequestBody DemoRequest demoInfo);

}
```

Followed by the controller where the @RestController was defined

Part of the controller:

```
@RestController
public class Democontroller implements Demoapi\<DemoRequest, DemoResponse\>{
static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Democontroller.class);

@Autowired
private DemoService demoService;


@Override
public ResponseEntity<DemoResponse> demo(@RequestBody DemoRequest demoInfo) {
DemoResponse demoResponse=new DemoResponse();
try {
demoResponse = demoService.demofun(demoInfo);
//logic
}
```

```
Now I want to modify this for the GET call and this is the modification I am using.
```

```
@SuppressWarnings("hiding")
```

```
@FunctionalInterfacepublic interface Demoapi<Void, DemoResponse>{ // as there is no request @GetMapping(value = "/v1/demo")public ResponseEntity<DemoResponse> demo(@RequestParam(name="q", required = false defaultValue="...") String name);// the get call has an optional query param}
```

```
Followed by the controller where the @RestController was defined

Part of the controller:
```

```
@RestControllerpublic class Democontroller implements Demoapi<Void, DemoResponse>{static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Democontroller.class);
```

```
@Autowiredprivate DemoService demoService;
```

```
@Overridepublic ResponseEntity<DemoResponse> demo(@RequestParam(name="q", required = false , defaultValue="...") String name) {DemoResponse demoResponse=new DemoResponse();try {demoResponse = demoService.demofun(name);//logic}
```

```
This set up works fine when tested in local but when deployed as Lambda ( I provide Handler as com.demo.DemoHandler in the AWS console, and in the Environment Variable under FUNCTION_NAME I give the DemoController class with the Starting letter in small caps i.e demoController ) and the lambda throws the following error when tested in the console as well as directed from an API Gateway:

\*2023-02-17 11:24:04.080  INFO 10 --- \[           main\] lambdainternal.AWSLambda                 : Started AWSLambda in 2.649 seconds (JVM running for 3.349)
2023-02-17 11:24:04.329 ERROR 10 --- \[           main\] c.f.c.c.BeanFactoryAwareFunctionRegistry : Failed to invoke function 'domainController'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
\*
```

Answer (score 0):

As per error seems like Handler going to find @RestController **'domainController'**
In your code there is all **Democontroller**

The bean for the demoController not defined properly.